# props is not applied although passed it to styled component

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

## What I want to do

**Changing colors depending on props passed from a component using `styled component`.**

## Problem

**`SmallButton` component definitely gets `props` but it doesn't change like props indicates.**

I would like to change styles of `SmallButton` depending on `props` that a component gives to the button component.
`SmallButton` has these props but it doesn't change at all.

I would like you to teach me how to solve it.

Thank you very much.

===   ====   ===   ===
My code is like this.

Header.jsx

```
render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Wrapper>
          {/* CSS Grid( 1 : 1 : 1) 左 */}
          <Image src={Logo} alt="" />
          {/* CSS Grid( 1 : 1 : 1) 中央 */}
          <SearchBox />
          {/* CSS Grid( 1 : 1 : 1) 右 */}
          {this.props.isAuthenticated ? (
            <>
              <div>
                <MessageToUserDiv>
                  <span>Hello {this.state.loginUser.username}</span>　
                  <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogout}>Logout</LogoutButton>
                </MessageToUserDiv>
                <AuthButtonDiv>
                  <SmallButton
                    btn_border="#466A80"
                    btn_back="#466A80"
                    btn_text_color="#D9F1FF"
                    btn_name="Post"
                    btn_click={this.jumpToPostGive}
                  />
                  <SmallButton
                    btn_border="#466A80"
                    btn_back="#8DD6FF"
                    btn_text_color="#466A80"
                    btn_name="Info"
                    btn_click=""
                  />
                </AuthButtonDiv>
              </div>
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <div>
                <p>Hello Guest</p>
                <AuthButtonDiv>
                  <SmallButton btn_name="Register" btn_click={this.jumpToRegister} />
                  <SmallButton btn_name="Login" btn_click={this.jumpToLogin} />
                </AuthButtonDiv>
              </div>
            </>
          )}
        </Wrapper>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  background-color: #8dd6ff;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2.3fr 1fr;
  padding: 10px 5px 5px 5px;
`;

const Image = styled.img`
  width: 230px;
  margin-top: 5px;
`;

const MessageToUserDiv = styled.div`
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: right;
  height: 20%;
`;

const LogoutButton = styled.button`
  color: #6e787f;
  width: 30%;
`;

const AuthButtonDiv = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 80%;
`;
```

SmallButton.jsx

```
class SmallButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <StyledButton
        type={this.props.btn_type}
        onClick={this.props.btn_click}
        onSubmit={this.props.btn_submit}
        disabled={this.props.btn_disable}
      >
        {this.props.btn_name}
      </StyledButton>
    );
}
}

const Colors = {
  main: '#8DD6FF',
  characters: '#6C7880',
  subcolor1: '#D9F1FF',
  accent1: '#70AACC',
  accent2: '#466A80',
};

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  font-size: 1.18em;
  border-radius: 7px;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 2px 3.5px;
  border: solid 2.5px;
  border-color: ${(props) => props.btn_border};
  background: ${(props) => props.btn_back};
  color: ${(props) => props.btn_text_color};
`;
```

Comment: Have you tried assigning it directly instead of using functions and returning the props. for example. `border-color: ${props.btn_border}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spread the rest for your props to StyledButton like this:

```
 <StyledButton
    type={this.props.btn_type}
    onClick={this.props.btn_click}
    onSubmit={this.props.btn_submit}
    disabled={this.props.btn_disable}
    {...this.props}
  >
    {this.props.btn_name}
  </StyledButton>
```

Comment: Now, it works fine thanks to you. Thank you very much. If it is possible, could you please tell me why it happened?

Comment: sure, you need to pass these props `btn_border="#466A80"  btn_back="#466A80"  btn_text_color="#D9F1FF"   btn_name="Post" btn_click={this.jumpToPostGive}` to the `StyledButton` but you didn't, that's why. `{...this.props}` means passing all props than you didn't mention manually

Comment: I would caution a bit on this pattern, if you accidentally also pass a `type`, `onClick`, `onSubmit`, etc... prop then the spread will overwrite the explicitly passed props above/before it. Either do the spread *before* the others, or destructure the explicit props and spread the rest.

Comment: @BesufkadMenji Thank you for teaching me that. I finally got it and I got to be able to use `styled component` a little bit. Thank you very much.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you for letting me know this advice. I am relived to know that. Thank you for helping me out at another question. I really appreciate your great help. Thank you very much.